# How to prevent unification when animating in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I am trying to create an animated gif where text drops down and smashes into the background and cracks it. Whenever I try and transform it though, the transformation is applied to all frames. How do I prevent this? I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64-bit)

Comment: Is it applied to all layers or all frames?

Comment: No, I'm only applying it to a single frame.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, all layers in your PSD are transformed when you try to transform just the text layer? Are the layers maybe linked?

Comment: I'm not using layers, I'm using frames for animating in photoshop

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. You said 'Whenever I try and transform it though, **the transformation is applied to all layers.**'

Comment: Sorry changed to frames.

Comment: Ok that makes it clear :) I'm not an expert with animating in Photoshop, but as far as I know you have to use different layers for different views in frames (from PS CS4, used to be different before that). That means that you have to duplicate the text layer, transform that one, and make the right layers visible for each frame separately. I'm not completely sure if there are other ways to do it though.

Comment: Oh god that's going to take forever :/

Comment: Yeah, it's not a great animating environment in my opinion. You might save some time though, if you take into account that when you make a new frame, it'll be the same as the last existing frame. Sometimes that saves you from having to make a lot of frames (un)visible.

Comment: @Zach I imagine you could probably save time by putting all your layers in a layer group, duplicating that the appropriate number of times, etc. If you've got access to Fireworks it's probably better suited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layer position and opacity can be animated. The actual pixels in a bitmap layer can not. The solution is to move the layer with the move tool when you want to animate the position, and duplicate the layer when you need to make destructive changes to the bitmap itself.

Answer (score 1):

In cc2017 there is an option on the right corners in the options thats called new layers visible in all frames. Thats auto turned on but turning it off should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox in the layers panel on the right labeled "propagate frame..." Make sure this is un-checked.
[image: example of checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the layer you are trying to move is a smart object and that you arent formally "transforming" it with the handles on the side but just moving it with the cursor.